# I want this <p> tag to come bottom of the image?

Tags: html, css

I am totally new to this html/css I am trying to do float a text with background as image .Yes I did that but the problem is the text is floating on top of the image.If use margin-top to adjust the image,it just simple pull down the whole div.Here down i gave a pictorial representation of what I want.

[image]

html

```
<div class="maincon">
    <div class="picon" style="background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .02), rgba(0, 0, 0, .8)), url('img/apple.jpg') "><p>Hi</p> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
.maincon {
    margin-top: 95px;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.picon {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    background: none center/cover #f2f2f2;
}

.picon p {

}
```

Comment: You should utilise position absolute on the `p` rather than trying to fix it with margins

Comment: No if i give position absolute P tag is floating my header while scrolling @AndyHolmes

Comment: You make the parent element position relative bud, that's how it works :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wihtout position `absolute` and `relative` .you can use `flexbox` module.it supports all latest browsers.

```css
.element {
  height: 80vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .02), rgba(0, 0, 0, .8)), url('http://cdn2.macworld.co.uk/cmsdata/features/3598128/iphone_6s_review_20.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  align-items: flex-end;
  display: flex;
}
p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <p>Apple iphone</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not great for cross-browser compatibility, particularly in IE - http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox. The `position` based answer is better.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `position: absolute`

```css
.element {
  height: 100vh;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .02), rgba(0, 0, 0, .8)), url('http://cdn2.macworld.co.uk/cmsdata/features/3598128/iphone_6s_review_20.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">
  <p>Apple iphone</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is if I use position:absolute P tag floating my header

Comment: Can you create fiddle and show that? I am not sure what you mean https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/114/

Comment: Not if you put position relative on it's parent @Vigneshwarar like this code shows

Comment: use flexbox model as i did in my answer

Comment: This is a better answer than the accepted one, in my opinion. This is the "standard" way of doing this, and will work across all relevant browsers and platforms. Flexbox is still has issues, particularly in IE http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: This is definitely the better choice of code to use. Flexbox isn't supported enough to warrant the accepted answer IMO

Answer (score 1):

```
.maincon {
    margin-top: 95px;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.picon {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    background: none center/cover #f2f2f2;
    position: relative;
}

.picon p {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;

}
```